# In Objective-C, How to initialize NSMutableArray with objects in another NSMutableArray using tableView reference

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmutablearray, nstableview

Developing for MacOS, I have an NSMutableArray namesArray[] that contains 3 String objects.
namesArray[] is represented in a tableView, where user can select multiple cells, each cell represents a single object.
I am trying to initialize a second NSMutableArray savedNamesArray[], and add objects from the original namesArray[] based on the selected cells in my tableView using this method:

```
NSMutableArray *savedNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[namesArray objectsAtIndexes:[_tableView selectedRowIndexes]], nil];
```

The problem is, no matter how many objects I select, only one gets added to the new NSMutableArray. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show the code on how you did connect the array with the table and how you catch the selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding one object, an array, to `savedNamesArray`. Use `initWithArray:` instead.

```
NSMutableArray *savedNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[namesArray objectsAtIndexes:[_tableView selectedRowIndexes]]];
```